# How to migrate a model with special type using loopback.js to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs

The automigrate.js works correctly and creates the food table in my postgres database, but the "real" types are mapped into "integer" types in my DB. 
The "allergens" that I want to be mapped into an "array" type is mapped to integer instead. 
Where is the error? What do I have to change?
I follow this [this tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/PostgreSQL-connector.html#postgresql-types-to-loopback)

This is my model.js

```
   {
  "name": "Food",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "postgres": {
        "columnName": "name",
        "dataType": "CHARACTER VARYING",
        "dataLength": 50,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }
    },
    "carbs": {
      "type": "number",
      "dataType": "real",
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 2,
      "required": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "carbs",
        "dataType": "real",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 2,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }
    },
    "fats": {
      "type": "number",
      "dataType": "REAL",
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 2,
      "required": true,
      "postgres": {
        "columnName": "fats",
        "dataType": "REAL",
        "dataLength": 50,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 2,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }
    },
    "proteins": {
      "type": "number",
      "dataType": "REAL",
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 2,
      "required": true,
      "postgres": {
        "columnName": "proteins",
        "dataType": "REAL",
        "dataLength": 50,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 2,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }
    },
    "allergens": {
      "type": ["object"]
    },
    "style": {
      "type": "object",
      "postgres": {
        "columnName": "style",
        "dataType": "CHARACTER VARYING",
        "dataLength": 50,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and this is my automigrate.js

```
'use strict';

var app = require('../server');
var dataSource = app.dataSources.softNutritionDB;

dataSource.automigrate('Food', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  dataSource.disconnect();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"allergens": {
   "type": ["object"]
 },
```

to,

```
"allergens": {
   "type": "object"
    "postgres": {
      "dataType": "json"
    }
 },
```

I ll create a json column.

This should work but ideally, as per normalization rules you should be creating another table to store allergens mappings.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday I created a different table for allergens and it worked. Do you have also a solution for the real values?

Comment: What do you mean by real values?

Comment: I mean real numbers (e.g. 3.45, 10.23, 733.124, ...). It seems that the only way to migrate a model with real numbers, is to migrate a number and then modify the table in postgres.

Comment: If you have an array, you need to mention type as json. Loopback can not change the datatype in a migration.